# What is the difference between a static and a non-static class?

Tags: c#

May someone explain me the difference between these two classes?

I am always using the first one, but I the the second one often as well.

```
public static class Test
{
    public static void Method()
    {

    }
}


public class Test
{
    public static void Method()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: `static` classes can only have static methods, fields and properties. So in your first example class `Test` may only have static members and in the second one both, static and instance members.

Comment: [What query do you have that is not answered in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx)?

Comment: Did you do any research? Come oooonnnn..!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx  should help

Comment: instead of typing a question here you must have typed in google thousands of results will be available

Comment: @Christian, your question is an exact duplicate. To prevent downvotes always do a relevant search on SO first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first class is static, which means:

- You can't use it as a type argument
- You can't use it as a variable type
- It will have *no* instance constructors (whereas your non-static class implicitly has a public parameterless constructor)
- It will be implicitly abstract and sealed (even though that combination can't be static
- It cannot contain any non-static members
- It can contain extension methods (if it's a top level, non-generic static class)

Basically for utility classes which are only *meant* to contain static members, using a static class expresses that intent clearly and lets the compiler help you enforce that usage.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: I'll edit that to "instance constructors"

Comment: +1 Fine answer, as always.

Answer (score 1):

A static class cannot ever be instantiated, and can only have static members. In your second code snippet, you could create create an instance of `Test`, but not in the first.

Answer (score 0):

Static class can only contain static member with is the first one. Second one is non static class and can contain both static and not static.

> A class can be declared static, indicating that it contains only
>   static members. It is not possible to create instances of a static
>   class using the new keyword. Static classes are loaded automatically
>   by the .NET Framework common language runtime (CLR) when the program
>   or namespace containing the class is loaded, [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).